# PostgreSQL: How to GRANT permission to GRANT permission in specific SCHEMA

Tags: postgresql, permissions, database-schema, sql-grant

I have a sample database containing **two schemas** and I have **two roles** in the database.

I need to grant rights in a way that

- 1. role can grant all permission **within schema #1** (nowhere else)
- 2. role can grant all permission **within schema #2** (nowhere else)

(essentially "schema-specific admins")

Would someone know a possible approach to this?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways:

- the “administrator role” for each schema owns the objects in that schema – then the requirement is automatically fulfilled
- all objects are owned by the same role, and that role uses `GRANT ... WITH GRANT OPTION` on all tables in each schema to the respective administrative role

I'd prefer the first option, because it is simpler.

Comment: Makes sense. But how do you specify the "administrator role" on a schema level?

Comment: Make that role the owner of the respective schema. Unless you grant extra permissions on that schema, only the owner can create tables in it.